Laravel app does not run in browser while all things are right in Docker
I want to dockerize a laravel project that is connected to PostgreSQL.
this is my Dockerfile :
FROM php:8.2-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html/myprojectsname

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libonig-dev \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libpq-dev \
    postgis \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

RUN echo "upload_max_filesize = 100M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini \
    && echo "post_max_size = 100M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

COPY . /var/www/html/myprojectsname

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/myprojectsname \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/myprojectsname/storage

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html/myprojectsname

RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181

This is the DokcerCompose.yml file content:
version: '3.8'

services:

    myprject:
        container_name: myprject

        image : "laravel-app"

        working_dir: /var/www/html/myprojectname

        build: .
        volumes:
            - ../myprojectname:/var/www/html/myprojectname
        ports:
            - "8014:80"
        command: bash -c 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'

        depends_on:
            postgres_serv:
                condition: service_healthy  
        restart: on-failure  

        networks:
            - webServiceNet

    postgres_serv:
        container_name: postgres_serv
        image: "postgres_postgis"

        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ../postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=ahmadbadpey
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - webServiceNet
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U myuser"]
            interval: 10s
            retries: 5
            timeout: 2s

    pgAdmin:
        container_name: pgadmin-ProjectName
        image: "dpage/pgadmin4:latest"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ../pgAdmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
            - ../pgadmin-password.txt:/pgadmin-password.txt
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=ahmad@gmail.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD_FILE=../pgadmin-password.txt
            - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        networks:
            - webServiceNet

networks:
    webServiceNet:
        driver: bridge

after running the docker-compose up command all things worked fine (including migration and serve command) but when I open http://localhost:8014/ or http://0.0.0.0:8000/ or other suggested addresses Nothing happens and nothing is displayed.

i suppose that You have built container myprject  based on your Dockerfile, and in it You are serving laravel app on port 8181 and exposing same port  - 8181
And in your yaml file you are using specifig congiuration

Shouldn't the binding be 8014:8181 instead?

I did this but still the problem is not solved

also this line in yaml is not necessary
command: bash -c 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'  you are already have artisan serve  in your Dockerfile, maybe add migrations to Dockerfile. After you have changed port have you restarted docker container myprject ?

yes, I restarted it sometimes. Now when I changed dockefile like this CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 EXPOSE 8000 problem is sovled. Is this a correct and safe way to solve this problem?

it should be you have changed port in your Dockerfile if i understand it correctly ? Any chnages in yaml file ?

I just changed in the Dockerfile. no changes in yml file.

and you are accessing it on localhost:8000 ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
